# How to solve the strptime() caused naive datetime RuntimeWarning?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to code without throwing any warnings in my console. So far I have been pretty good at avoiding it until this one case, which seems like a chicken and egg situation to me.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt 

last_contacted = "19/01/2013"
current_tz = timezone.get_current_timezone()
date_time = dt.strptime(last_contacted, get_current_date_input_format(request))
date_time = current_tz.localize(date_time)
```

The third line is throwing this warning:

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-01-19
>   00:00:00) while time zone support is active.)

Its kind of odd, since I need to convert the unicode into a datetime first before I can convert the datetime object into an datetime-aware object (with timezone support) in the forth line.

Any suggestions from experts?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
def get_current_date_input_format(request):
    if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en-gb':
        return formats_en_GB.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS[0]
    elif request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en':        
        return formats_en.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS[0]
```

Comment: What's your 'dt' variable?

Comment: updated question, `from datetime import datetime as dt `

Comment: need to see the source of your `get_current_date_input_format` function as well...

Comment: This RuntimeWarning only occurs when you assign naive datetime objects to Model instances, so your example code shown shouldn't give this warning unless `get_current_date_input_format` is doing something special.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with the requested information.  I have noticed if I combine line 3 and line 4, I won't get the warning at all.  How strange..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the comments to your question I am guessing that what you really have in your code is something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt 

last_contacted = "19/01/2013"
current_tz = timezone.get_current_timezone()
model_instance.date_time = dt.strptime(last_contacted, get_current_date_input_format(request))
model_instance.date_time = current_tz.localize(date_time)
```

where `model_instance` is an instance of a Model which has a DateTimeField named `date_time`.

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    ....
    date_time = DateTimeField()
```

The Python [`datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) function returns a naive `datetime` object which you are attempting to assign to the `DateTimeField` which is then generating a warning because the use of non-naive `datetime` objects is incorrect when timezone support is enabled.

If you combine the calls to `strptime` and `localize` on a single line, then the complete calculation of converting from a naive `datetime` to non-naive `datetime` is done before assigning to `date_time` and so you *won't* get an error in this case.

Additional note:  Your `get_current_date_input_format` function should return some default timezone to use in the event that there is no timezone in the request, otherwise the `strptime` call will fail.

Comment: current_tz.localize(...) (or utc.localize(...)) is the key line here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on USE_TZ in your [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-USE_TZ) file?

```
USE_TZ = True
```

Also, from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#code) there are some more specific steps you can take.